# Which Magento modules allow to set tiered pricing depending on category?

Tags: cart

May I ask for a recommendation for a module to offer tiered pricing across a category?  We have a sale coming up.  We want tiered pricing but have a couple hundred products.

Comment: I would say this is possible via sales rules.

Comment: We bought an extension.  Price rules was part of it.  The extension allowed for the quantity of products across multiple ccategories to be counted in quantity totals for discounts. Thank you for everyones time.

Comment: Which extension did you buy?

Comment: http://bluejalappeno.com/  We bought their Tiered Pricing Across Multiple Products Extension. I run DHP.org.  We use it for running sales across books, cards, etc...  I appreciate your time and input.